# Как убрать домен из всех ссылок в WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно убрать домен со всех ссылок wp , что бы был вид не `http://domain.com/post`, а просто `/post`?

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
function remove_home_from_permalink( $url ) {
  return str_replace( home_url(), "", $url );
}

add_filter('the_permalink','remove_home_from_permalink');
```

Не помогает...

Comment: Тогда лучше меняй движок. Почему - прямо в первых абзацах https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: Та я уже понял , что это проблема. Но движок менять не вариант.Делаю так: <?php echo str_replace( home_url(), "", get_permalink() ); ?> там где это возможно.

Comment: Проблема не в ВП, а в том, что рождаются такие хотелки и такие "решения"

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать функцию [wp_make_link_relative()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_make_link_relative/) для этих целей, как в фильтре, так и прицельно там, где нужно

То есть получится что-то вроде этого

```
function remove_home_from_permalink($url) {
    return wp_make_link_relative($url);
}

add_filter('the_permalink','remove_home_from_permalink');
```